# Selenium WebDriver Focus Jumps to IEDriverServer.exe CMD Window

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am using Selenium 2.35 and .Net4.5 with IE to validate a webpage. One series of tests fills a text box with SendKeys(),  clicks the save button,  switches to the logon dialog and closes it then repeats for 3 more text boxes. On my usual test machine this works great but running the same test on a different machine it breaks. After handling the logon dialog the IEDriverServer.exe CMD window is brought to focus and the subsequent test fails because the browser is no longer in focus.

Does anyone know why the IEDriverServer.exe CMD window gets focus and how I can prevent this?

Comment: What version of the IEDriver is it? What version of IE? 32bit? 64bit? What are the differences between your machine and the machine it's reproducible on? How are the tests run?

Comment: Both Machines have IEDriver 2.33, IE 10 and 64bit Windows 7. The tests are run from an automation suite. Each webpage is validated one at a time each with its own WebDriver. The WebDriver is instantiated, the page is loaded, every element tested then the WebDriver is disposed.

Comment: I updated IEDriver to 2.35.3 and have the same behavior on both machines.

Comment: Using what? MSTest? NUnit? How are they launched? Through TeamCity? TFS? NUnit's own console? Visual Studio?

Comment: Our own test automation suite launched through Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to force focus using the RequireWindowFocus property

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.RequireWindowFocus = true;
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
//navigate and sendkeys now
```